# why react-router V4 component not loading?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

I have an Home component and this is inside of it:

```
{posts && posts.map(post => (
  <div key={post.id}>
  <Link to="/test">{post.title}</Link>
  </div>
))}
<Route path="/test" component={Test} />
```

this is my app.js

```
<Topnav />        
<Switch>
  <Route exact path = '/' component={Home} />
  <Route path = '/posts/create' component={Postform} />        
</Switch>
```

Why is this test not working when I click it? It goes the the url but the Test component should say `I AM TEST`!

```
class Test extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>I AM TEST</h1>  
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Move `/test` Route to `app.js`

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the following line:

```
<Route path="/test" component={Test} />
```

inside the `<Switch>` component instead of inside `Home`.

Answer (score 0):

Your components are counter-intuitive. You have a `Home` component which renders **only** for `/`, then inside that you have another `Route` which, as a consequence, will never be rendered as it doesn't render on `/`. You should instead put your `/test` component inside the `Switch` in `app.js`.

Note: that you can't solve this just by removing `exact` for `/` as then the `Home` component would render on **every** URL.